# Xcode project "enable recommended warnings"

Tags: xcode

I just updated to Xcode 9.3. I opened my project and I have a Project Settings warning that says "Build Settings" with a checkmark and "Project "X" - Enable with Recommended Warnings" also with a checkmark. Under that it says

This will enable the following recommended compiler warnings:

- Implicit retain of 'self' within blocks
- Overriding Deprecated Objective-C Methods

Pressing "Perform Changes" brings up "The working copy X has uncommitted changes." and underneath: "Do you want to continue upgrading to the latest recommended settings and performing project cleanup? It may not be possible to undo this operation." With a continue button.

As a beginner I haven't seen this before and I don't want to break anything. My question is, what should I do? Is this normal behavior and should I allow it?

Comment: I did this and now I have random ads coving the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s typically fine to click through this alert and enable those warnings.

This is normal behavior, which typically occurs after updating Xcode to a new version.

Each Xcode project has a bunch of compiler settings, which can vary from project to project. Some of those determine which things in your code it will warn you about. There are a set of these that are turned on by default, and that set changes over time.

The second alert about the working copy having modified files is because you are using git and haven’t committed all changes.